# How to repeat an input without while loop?

Tags: python, list, input, append

I'm figuring out how to append inputs in my list, the problem is that some inputs are strings and others floats, so the question is if it's possible to iterate an input 2 times as string and 3 times as float without making a while/loop or for loop range, for example:

```
fighters = [[],[]]    

for i in range(len(fighters)):  
    for j in range(5):
        if j <= 1:
           fighters[i].append(input())

    else:
        fighters[i].append(float(input()))
```

And I don't know, make something like this (this is just a reference):

```
for i in range(len(fighters)):
    fighters[i].append(input(), 2) # that 2 means 2 times for example
    fighters[i].append(float(input(), 3) # and that 3 means 3 times
```

This is an example of the inputs:

```
Gabriel # i want this 2 as strings 
Wolf 
7.5 # and this 3 as floats 
5.1 
5.1 
Vlad # same here 
Vampire 
5.3 
7.8 
5.0
```

Comment: If you multiply the value times an int, you will get the value repeated that number of times, if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you looking to get the user to input 2 strings and 3 floating point numbers? Do you expect the user to know what to enter? Or are you getting the input from standard in in some other way?

Comment: @Grismar this is one input  for example:

`Gabriel # i want this 2 as strings
Wolf
7.5 # and this 3 as floats
5.1
5.1
Vlad # same here
Vampire
5.3
7.8
5.0`


so I want my code to receive this input and as you can see it has 2 strings and 3 float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(fighters)):
    for cls in (str,)*2 + (float,)*3:
        fighters[i].append(cls(input()))
```

`(str,)` is a tuple with one element, the extra comma is needed.
`(str,) * 2` maps to `(str, str)`
so `(str,)*2 + (float,)*3` maps to `(str, str, float, float, float)`

Comment: the code send me this error: 

`File "Solution.py", line 58
    fighters[i].append(cls(input())
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: Awesome it worked!, could you please explain what the CLS does? i just for understand what I'm doing.

Comment: `cls` is a variable which gets the succesive values `str,str, float, float, float` for each iteration. `str` and `float` are python classes. When `cls` has the value `float` and you do `cls(input())`, thats the same as `float(input())` which creates a new float object initializing it with the value returned by input() (or in other words converting the input to float).
When `cls` has the value `str` it converts the input to `str` which does nothing because the input is already a str.
The tricky part is that in python, classes are also objects and can be stored in variables as any other object